# See query result instead of query text in Postgresql SET variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use `SET` in Postgresql to set a query result as a variable.

```
SET var.foo = SELECT first_name from names where id = ''10''';

SELECT current_setting('var.foo') AS FirstName;
```

Instead of seeing `Paul` in the `FirstName` column I see `SELECT first_name from names where id = '10'`.

How do I see the query result instead of the query text?

Comment: You cannot directly assign the result of a SELECT query to a custom configuration parameter using the SET command. The SET command is used for setting configuration parameters, not for storing the results of a query.  Use a PL/pgSQL function or a DO block where you can declare variables and execute queries to assign values to these variables.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com [Yes, you can.](https://dbfiddle.uk/0nE-QTdQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) which is a function equivalent of `SET`, similar to how `current_setting()` you used is a function for `SHOW`;

```
select set_config('my.var'::text,
                  (select 'here goes your select'::text),
                  false);
```

| set_config |
| --- |
| here goes your select |

```
show my.var;
```

| my.var |
| --- |
| here goes your select |

```
select current_setting('my.var');
```

| current_setting |
| --- |
| here goes your select |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qng51r-C)